# ArcGIS Model Builder perform split operation on each selected feature and delete identical on collection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, features

I have created a model to select parcels and create segments for each parcel. If two parcels are sharing the same segment, delete duplicate. My model is attached.

My question is: Before appending or deleting identicals, I need to perform the action on a whole. The model I created is executing for each feature. Please advice..!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a [Collect Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004000000005000000) before the Append tool, it will collect the iterated and processed features uphill, then append and delete once for the whole collection.

Connect the output of 'Split Line at Vertices to Collect Values, the the output of Collect Values to Append:

[image]

Comment: I added the collect Values but i was not able to give the link from collect values.

Comment: What do you mean by 'give the link'?

Comment: Sorry it is connection from Collected values to Append

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: The Output Values from the Collects Values tool needs to be exposed as a parameter and the whole model from iterator to collects value needs to be put in a sub-model. Then you have the master model with the sub-model feeding into the append tool. The model will run far more efficiently.